# Remove lines with an infinite value from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], 
             [2, float('inf'), 3, 4],
             [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

I would like to remove the lines that contain an infinite value in them so that the results would be

```
np.array([[1,2,3,4],
          [5,6,7,8]])
```

I tried to do `A = A[float('inf') not in A]`, but the result is `array([], shape=(0, 3, 4), dtype=float64)`.

I could do

```
B = []
for line in A:
    if float('inf') not in line:
        B.append(line)
A = np.array(B)
```

but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have a `NumPy` array, a `NumPy` based solution will perform much better than using python lists.You can use [`np.isinf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) with [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) here:

```
A[~np.isinf(A).any(1)]

array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [5., 6., 7., 8.]])
```

---

```
is_inf = np.isinf(A) # returns True when there is an Inf
print(is_inf)

array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])

is_inf_any = is_inf.any(1) # Checks is there are any Trues along axis 1 
                           # (hence reduces along that axis)
print(is_inf_any)

# array([False,  True, False])

~is_inf_any # applies a bitwise logical not
# array([ True, False,  True])
```

Comment: Nice answer. What does it mean `any(1)` ?

Comment: What does the `~` mean?

Comment: `~` means `not`. That means `not isinf`

Comment: `.any(1)` means it is checking if any line evaluates to `True`.

Comment: And the `1` in `.any(1)` is the axis along which to perform the comparison, I think

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *list comprehension* for this.

```
A = np.array([line for line in A if float('inf') not in line])
```